# uWSGI loads Django apps in wrong order (alphabetically instead of as in the order defined in INSTALLED_APPS)

Tags: django, uwsgi

I have a Django project running in an virtualenv on uwsgi controlled by supervisord. 
In the Django project I have a an extra directory 'apps/' where I put all my Django apps. In my settings.py I add the 'apps/' directory to the python path so the Django apps in it are found.

This works very good with runserver. But I have uwsgi in my production environment. When I start the server, the Django apps are load in alphabetical order as they are in the filesystem and not in the order definded by INSTALLED_APPS.

An example: I have these apps in my filesystem:

```
/home/anton/project/apps/events
/home/anton/project/apps/profiles
/home/anton/project/apps/routes
```

Profiles are my extended user profiles, routes are bike routes and events depends on routes because an event can have 1..n routes.

So in my INSTALLED_APPS it is defined this way:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   # .. django stuff ..
   'profiles',
   'routes',
   'events',
]
```

In the models.py of the events app I import models from the routes app. As long as the Django apps are loaded in the order specified in INSTALLED_APPS setting everything works fine. But uWSGI loads the Django apps in alphabetical ordering. And because events is loaded before routes I get the following error in the models.py from events app:

```
ImportError at /
cannot import name Route

/myproject/app/src/apps/events/models.py in <module>
    from routes.models import Route
```

So when loading the events app, uwsgi does not know about the routes app.
Should'nt it be that uwsgi loads all the python modules (read: Django apps) and then start executing the request?

Every hint is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Anton

PS:

Here is my uwsgi.ini configuration (maybe this helps)

```
[uwsgi]
http-socket = :8081
master = true
workers = 8

pidfile = /tmp/uwsgi-project.pid

chdir = /project/app/src/apps/
pythonpath = /project/app/src/
module = wsgi
virtualenv = /home/anton/.virtualenvs/project/

env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings
logto = /project/log/uwsgi-bikemap.log

max-requests = 5000
vacuum = true
```

'/project/app/src/' is where the Django project is. '/project/app/src/apps' is where the Django apps are. The wsgi.py (referenced by module = wsgi) is in '/project/app/src/'

Comment: Does something modify `sys.path`, perhaps?

Comment: In my settings.py I insert the '/project/app/src/apps/' directory to sys.path (on index 0). See the uwsgi configuration an the notes in the question. (just added them)

Comment: That's probably going to be it; if that gets delayed until after it's listening, that would happen. I don't know; I'm not familiar with uwsgi.

Comment: But when I get the Django Error Page the directory added to python path in settings.py is displayed in the error message in the path. I also tried to add it to the uswgi config with no success.. Right now I think about the ordering the apps in INSTALLED_APPS are loaded... Any other ideas?

Comment: There could be something else causing failure of import... I don't know; I can offer no more assistance on the matter.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the help! You pointed me in the right direction. Right now I know, that uwsgi is loading the django apps in my '/project/app/src/apps/' in alphabetical order as they appear in the directory and not in the order given in INSTALLED_APPS variable. And this is causing the problem. Now I only have to find out, how to tell uwsgi to load the apps in the right order! :)

Comment: Thanks god uWSGI has not that feature (would be completely foolish) ;) You need to check if you have circular dependancies problems and some import is failing

Comment: @Anton according to [this](http://lists.unbit.it/pipermail/uwsgi/2011-April/001871.html) you dont need supervisord. Try to install latest vershion of uWSGI over pip.